# Get List Page Checkins Using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

When I view the page object for a page I own ( https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN] ), it shows:

```
{
   ...
   "checkins":4
   ...
}
```

Directly viewing the page on facebook shows 4 checkins as well.

However, when I try and view the checkins field using the graph api ( https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]/?fields=checkins&access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN] ), it shows the following:

```
{
   "checkins": {
      "data": [

      ]
   }
}
```

I also tried using the page access token, but that didn't work either.

I have enabled the user_checkins, friends_checkins, and publish_checkins permissions.

I experience the same problem when I change `?fields=checkins` to `?fields=likes`.

Can anybody shed some light on this, or tell me how to get a list checkins for a particular page?

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing the Page's checkins like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]/checkins?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

as well as likes:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]/likes?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

Comment: I did some more testing with a different user, who I assigned as admin to the page and gave the same permissions ("manage_pages","user_checkins","friends_checkins","user_likes","friends_likes"), and it seems to partially work for that user (using "/checkins..." and /?fields=checkins..."). I say partially work because the number of "items" returned in the data set doesn't match the the checkins count in the main page object. Again, both users have the same permissions. Getting the likes data set doesn't work for either users (either using using "/checkins..." or /?fields=checkins...")

Comment: Wait so you're using a /page_id to look for a users checkins? Or are you querying /user_id/checkins?

Comment: I'm using a /page_id to get all checkins for that page, regardless of user.
I just created a new checkin for some additional testing and now the page object for that page shows a count of 5 checkins, but drilling down to the checkins connection for that page only shows one item in the data set (implying only 1 checkin). I still can't figure out why the number of items in the checkins connection data set doesn't match the checkins count for the page object.